# Convert string format to date

Tags: java, date

I am trying  to convert string in to date in Java. I am able to convert but I'm not getting the desired output.

I am using the code.

```
String="2016-02-20"
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date12 = formatter.parse(date)
```

I am getting the following output:

```
Sat Feb 20 00:00:00 IST 2016
```

but I want same output as string have but want in date type only,
like:

```
2016-02-20.
```

How can I  do this.

Comment: If at all possible, you should be using the new [Java Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package instead of Date et al.  I don't know what you're doing to persist it to the database, but several of the ORMs support it by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## java.time

You should be using the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. Avoid the troublesome old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day nor time zone.

Your input string is already in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. This format is used by default in java.time. So no need to specify a parsing pattern.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2016-02-20" );
```

The `toString` implementation uses the same ISO 8601 format when generating a textual representation of your date value.

```
String output = localDate.toString();  // Emits: "2016-02-20"
```

For other formats, search StackOverflow on how to use `DateTimeFormatter` in the java.time.format package.

### Database

For transfer to a database, use JDBC. Hopefully the JDBC drivers will be updated to use java.time types directly. Until then, convert to the java.sql types.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( localDate );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same output then why are you converting it to the `Date` Object in the first place? `Date` Object holds date with time.

From JAVADoc of Date:

> The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision.

You can't just remove time out of it.

Comment: because my sql  i have only datefield where i need to pass this in my sql query

Comment: You'll need to convert `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date`. Do it like this: `new java.sql.Date(date12.getTime());`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SimpleDateFormat for output:

```
String onlyDate = formatter.format(date12);
```

If you want to save this date to mysql you can also use method `setDate` of `PreparedStatement`.